Extraneous argument label error of a nested function in swift
I am trying to understand argument labels in Swift and working with a following code example:
func getGreetFn(greeting: String) -> (String) -> Void {
  func greetFn(person: String) {
    print("\(greeting) \(person)")
  }

  return greetFn
}

let greet = getGreetFn(greeting: "Hi")
greet(person: "John")

Problem:
The above code example throws the following error:
error: extraneous argument label 'person:' in call
greet(person: "John")
     ^~~~~~~~~

Question:
According to my understanding, argument labels are required by default. So, why person label of the greet function is causing an error? Removing the person label fixes the error.
Swift version: 5.9.2
